# Simple taylor approximation in macroeconomic model

Tags: macroeconomics

Define $\hat{y}=\log\frac{y_t}{y}$ which means percentage deviation from steady state.
Then $\hat{y}=s_c \hat{c}+s_i \hat{i} + s_g \hat{g}$ where $s_c +s_i +s_g =1$.
I can't derive that result.
Is that $\log s_c \approx s_c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At every time period, we have:
$$
y_t = c_t + i_t + g_t
$$
Long run steady state gives:
$$
y = c + i + g
$$
so, taking differences we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
&y_t - y = c_t - c + i_t - i + g_t - g,\\
\iff &\frac{y_t - y}{y} = \frac{c}{y}\frac{c_t - c}{c} + \frac{i}{y}\frac{i_t - i}{i}+ \frac{g}{y} \frac{g_t - g}{g}
\end{align*}
$$
Set $s_c = \dfrac{c}{y}, s_i = \dfrac{i}{y}$ and $s_g = \dfrac{g}{y}$ to be the shares of consumption, investment and government expenditures.

This gives:
$$
\frac{y_t - y}{y} = s_c \frac{c_t - c}{c} + s_i \frac{i_t - i}{i} + s_g \frac{g_t - g}{g}
$$
Now, we approximate the growth rates. For a variable $x_t$, consider a Taylor expansion of $\ln(x_t)$ around the steady state $x$
$$
\ln(x_t) \approx \ln(x) + \frac{(x_t - x)}{x}
$$
This gives $\dfrac{x_t - x}{x} \approx \ln(x_t) - \ln(x) = \ln \dfrac{x_t}{x}$. Substituting gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\ln\frac{y_t}{y} \approx s_c \ln \frac{c_t}{c} + s_i \ln \frac{i_t}{i} + s_g \ln \frac{g_t}{g}.\\
\iff &\hat y = s_c \hat c + s_i \hat i + s_g \hat g.
\end{align*}
$$